# Vue.js mini app with routes, hosted in child url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vue.js, vue-router

Yay!

I have up and running my first real world webapp made with vue.js!

It's a very simple wordpress posts viewer (list/single), for embedding in any website (In my case, a Hotel website) some published offers in the main Hotel Chain website.

It works PERFECT as standalone webapp (/folder/index.html in my local), and also vue router history mode, thanks to the magic of this apache .htaccess recipe:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /ofertasvue/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

My tests work perfectly, I have a posts list in:

/offers

and each post looks like

/offers/offer/3989

But I need to place this webapp in production inside the www.hotel.com/offers url.

The hotel site has its own .htaccess, of course, but I have not found the correct way to adapt this mod_rewrite recipe, I dont't see clear.

**www.hotel.com/offers** works great, but each offer goes when clicked to:

**http://www.hotel.com/http:/www.hotel.com/offers/offers/offer/3989** <- Yeah, repeated domain, repeated parent... It works, the only problem is that non-freandly route appearance...

Any of you, kids, had similar environment for production webapp, in a child url?

Found some documentation of routes, subroutes, nginx, donuts, etc, but I cannot see clearly the way, can you help me, please?

This are my two simple routes:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {path: '/offers/', component: Ofertas},
    {path: '/offers/offer/:id', name: 'oferta', component: Oferta},
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are making some mistake in while generating links for routes. Can you show us a piece of code where you generate links "http://www.hotel.com/http:/www.hotel.com/offers/offers/offer/3989"?